# PDFBox - sign PDF have existing signed by another

Tags: pdfbox

Trying to sign a PDF existing signed with PDFBox

[image: pdf]

with this test function :

```
/**
     * Test creating visual signature with the modernized example.
     *
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws CMSException
     * @throws OperatorCreationException
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException
     * @throws TSPException
     * @throws CertificateVerificationException
     */
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("signingTypes")
    void testCreateVisibleSignature2(boolean externallySign)
            throws IOException, CMSException, OperatorCreationException, GeneralSecurityException,
                   TSPException, CertificateVerificationException
    {
        // sign PDF
        String inPath = IN_DIR + "pdf.pdf";
        File destFile;

        CreateVisibleSignature2 signing = new CreateVisibleSignature2(keyStore, PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        Rectangle2D humanRect = new Rectangle2D.Float(200, 300, 200, 100);
        signing.setImageFile(new File(JPEG_PATH));

        signing.setExternalSigning(externallySign);
        destFile = new File(OUT_DIR + getOutputFileName("Signed.pdf", externallySign));
        signing.signPDF(new File(inPath), destFile, humanRect, tsa);

        checkSignature(new File(inPath), destFile, false);
    }
```

when try to setMDPPermission process :

```
if (doc.getVersion() >= 1.5f && accessPermissions == 0)
            {
                SigUtils.setMDPPermission(doc, signature, 2);
            }



 if (sig.getCOSObject().containsKey(COSName.CONTENTS))
            {
                throw new IOException("DocMDP transform method not allowed if an approval signature exists");
            }
```

but on this function SigUtils got error :

> java.io.IOException: DocMDP transform method not allowed if an
> approval signature exists

how can i pass the document to sign ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message "DocMDP transform method not allowed if an approval signature exists" is correct.

If you want to add a signature to an already signed PDF, simply remove the

```
if (doc.getVersion() >= 1.5f && accessPermissions == 0)
{
    SigUtils.setMDPPermission(doc, signature, 2);
}
```

block.

Comment: sorry my bad, the signature now successfully, but got error org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: array lengths differ, expected: <1602> but was: <1183>

in function checksignature(new File(inPath), destFile, false);

why this happen ?

Comment: @Lazar *"why this happen"* -  Hhmmm, difficult to tell, have you changed anything else in the example?

Comment: nothing changed, im clone the github today

Comment: In particular there are multiple assertions for array equality in `checksignature`... Can you determine which one failed and share the signed PDF?

Comment: CheckSignature is part of our build tests, you should find out what array is different and whether this is relevant to your application.